# How to simplify the get result form json

Tags: json, go

I want to get `redirectUrl` value. So I write code like this. I think is too complex. May be have some other way to get?

```golang
var v interface{}
req.ToJSON(&v)
a := v.(map[string]interface{})
b := a["browserPayment"].(map[string]interface{})
logs.Info(b["redirectUrl"])
```

This is response:

```
{"browserPayment":{"interaction":{"status":"INITIATED","timeInitiated":"xxxxxx"},"operation":"PAY","redirectUrl":"xxxxx","returnUrl":"http://localhost"},"gatewayEntryPoint":"xxxxx","merchant":"xxxxx","order":{"amount":1,"chargeback":{"amount":0,"currency":"USD"},"creationTime":"xxxxxx","currency":"USD","id":"xxxxxx","merchantAmount":1,"merchantCurrency":"USD","status":"INITIATED","totalAuthorizedAmount":0,"totalCapturedAmount":0,"totalRefundedAmount":0},"response":{"gatewayCode":"SUBMITTED"},"result":"SUCCESS","sourceOfFunds":{"type":"UNION_PAY"},"timeOfRecord":"xxxxxxx","transaction":{"acquirer":{"id":"xxxxxxx","merchantId":"xxxxx"},"amount":1,"currency":"USD","id":"xxxxx","source":"INTERNET","type":"PAYMENT"},"version":"56"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable with a type that matches the structure of the data. Unmarshal to that value:

```
 var v struct { BrowserPayment struct { RedirectUrl string }}
 req.ToJSON(&v)
 logs.Info(v.BrowserPayment.RedirectUrl)
```

Suggestion: check and handle the error returned from ToJSON.